# Filtering the measuretypes from the databank in different formats during the data retrieving

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

In my C# code, I have written the code, that retrieves the data from MySQL database from different tables using Inner Join. I created two Formats Standard and extended Formats to retrieve the data. In Standard mode it should retrieve directly into excel and only four measure types which are input, output, Kalibration Input and Kalibration Output. And in Extended mode it retrieves all the other measurement types including these four types.

In settings of my Microsoft Visual Studio, I have given the values for the four measure types and also written in the code like below format:

```
if (combocustom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Standard")
{
    messungTableAdapter1.Fill(richtenDataSet1.Messung, Settings.Default.EinstellungEinganswertId, Settings.Default.EinstellungAusgangswertId, Settings.Default.EinstellungRohId, Settings.Default.EinstellungKaliInId, Settings.Default.EinstellungKaliOtId, dateVon, dateBis, machineId);
    einstellungTableAdapter1.Fill(richtenDataSet1.Einstellung, dateVon, dateBis, machineId);
    kalibrierungTableAdapter1.Fill(richtenDataSet1.Kalibrierung, machineId, dateVon, dateBis);'
```

and the Extended mode code looks like this:

```
else if (combocustom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Extended")
{
    messungTableAdapter1.FillBy(richtenDataSet1.Messung, Settings.Default.EinstellungEinganswertId, dateVon, dateBis, machineId, Settings.Default.EinstellungAusgangswertId,Settings.Default.EinstellungRohId,  Settings.Default.EinstellungKaliInId, Settings.Default.EinstellungKaliOtId);
    einstellungTableAdapter1.Fill(richtenDataSet1.Einstellung, dateVon, dateBis, machineId);
    kalibrierungTableAdapter1.Fill(richtenDataSet1.Kalibrierung, machineId, dateVon, dateBis);
```

and also developed a query for the data retrieving as shown below:

```
SELECT
    dmc.Code AS DMC,
    dmc.Part_Typ,
    association.cycleTime,
    result.typeString AS [IO/ NIO reason],
    typeMode.String AS [measurement type],
    FORMAT(measure.M_1, '0.000') AS M_1,
    FORMAT(measure.M_2, '0.000') AS M_2,
    FORMAT(measure.M_3, '0.000') AS M_3,
    FORMAT(measure.M_4, '0.000') AS M_4,
    FORMAT(measure.M_5, '0.000') AS M_5,
    FORMAT(measure.M_6, '0.000') AS M_6,
    FORMAT(measure.M_7, '0.000') AS M_7,
    FORMAT(measure.M_8, '0.000') AS M_8,
    FORMAT(measure.M_9, '0.000') AS M_9,
    FORMAT(measure.M_10, '0.000') AS M_10,
    FORMAT(measure.M_11, '0.000') AS M_11,
    FORMAT(measure.M_12, '0.000') AS M_12,
    FORMAT(measure.M_13, '0.000') AS M_13,
    FORMAT(measure.M_14, '0.000') AS M_14,
    FORMAT(measure.M_15, '0.000') AS M_15,
    FORMAT(measure.M_16, '0.000') AS M_16,
    FORMAT(measure.M_17, '0.000') AS M_17,
    FORMAT(measure.M_18, '0.000') AS M_18,
    FORMAT(measure.M_19, '0.000') AS M_19,
    FORMAT(measure.M_20, '0.000') AS M_20,
    CONVERT(DATE, measure.datetime) AS Date,
    CONVERT(TIME, measure.datetime) AS Time
FROM measure
INNER JOIN dmc ON measure.dmc = dmc.dmcId
INNER JOIN typeMode ON measure.type = typeMode.typeId
INNER JOIN association ON measure.associationId = association.Id
INNER JOIN result ON association.result = result.Id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        datetime,
        COUNT(*) AS occurrences
    FROM measure AS measure_1
    WHERE (type = @EingangsId)
    AND (datetime >= @dateVon)
    AND (datetime <= @dateBis)
    AND (machine = @machine)

    OR (type = @AusgangsId)
    AND (datetime >= @dateVon)
    AND (datetime <= @dateBis)
    AND (machine = @machine)

    OR (type = @raw)
    AND (datetime >= @dateVon)
    AND (datetime <= @dateBis)
    AND (machine = @machine)

    OR (type = @caliIn)
    AND (datetime >= @dateVon)
    AND (datetime <= @dateBis)
    AND (machine = @machine)

    OR (type = @caliOut)
    AND (datetime >= @dateVon)
    AND (datetime <= @dateBis)
    AND (machine = @machine)

    GROUP BY datetime
    HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
) AS derivedtbl_1 ON measure.datetime = derivedtbl_1.datetime
ORDER BY measure.Id
```

Initially I thought may be deleting the Raw can done and I can only get the data for the remaining four measurement types , but it didn't worked. If I delete the raw in SQL and in standard mode code, I can seen any results in my excel sheet. if I delete any other  for example if I delete Eingang from the code and SQL query, it is working and I am not able to see the results of eingang. perfectly working. But not working when I do the same by deleting the Raw.

Any suggestion in this on how to proceed to fornt.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Based on your column aliases and `FORMAT()` function, it looks like you are using SQL Server. Your `derivedtbl_1` does not work as you think it does, as it is missing the sets of parentheses to group the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. That `WHERE` clause looks like it can be simplified to just ``WHERE type IN (@EingangsId, @AusgangsId, @raw, @caliIn, @caliOut) AND datetime BETWEEN @dateVon AND @dateBis AND machine = @machine``. Your repeated `M_*` columns look to be in need of normalisation.

Comment: If you just want to remove Raw, you can remove OR (type = @raw) AND (datetime >= @dateVon) AND (datetime <= @dateBis) in your query
AND (machine = @machine). In addition, your query where can also be optimized. Can be optimized as WHERE ((type = @EingangsId) OR (type = @AusgangsId) OR (type = @caliIn) OR (type = @caliOut)) AND (datetime >= @dateVon) AND (datetime <= @dateBis) AND (machine = @machine)

Comment: yes, I tried that, i also written in my question about that "Initially I thought may be deleting the Raw can done and I can only get the data for the remaining four measurement types , but it didn't worked. If I delete the raw in SQL and in standard mode code, I can seen any results in my excel sheet. if I delete any other for example if I delete Eingang from the code and SQL query, it is working and I am not able to see the results of eingang. perfectly working. But not working when I do the same by deleting the Raw." - @GetValue

Comment: @MNK Hello, it seems that English is not your native language. Have you enabled the cache query function of mysql? If it is enabled, Raw may be deleted but the query result still has Raw. You can clear the mysql cache and try again.